# Encrypt to AES 128 ECB in HEX

Tags: encryption, openssl, hex, aes

I'm trying to use `openssl` to encrypt plain text into `AES 128 ECB` in `HEX`.

Using plain text `11111111111111111111111111111111` and raw key `00000000000000000000000000000000` I'm trying to use:

```
echo -n "11111111111111111111111111111111" | openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -K 00000000000000000000000000000000 -nosalt | xxd -p
```

But this gives me:

```
b6de54f9a78637d1eb523ca7201589f4b6de54f9a78637d1eb523ca72015
89f40143db63ee66b0cdff9f69917680151e
```

And I'm supposed to get:

```
FFA3C7ED04710B98067DAE6815E2751F
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to hex decode your plaintext. Furthermore, OpenSSL defaults to PKCS#7 padding, so you should disregard the last block of 16 bytes / 32 hex chars if you need a 16 byte output for a 16 byte input.

Comment: Can you hex decode by command line? Yeah sure. Can you cut 16 bytes or 32 characters from a string or stream? Yep, can be done. So yes... (not behind my linux home system at the moment, sorry).

Comment: @AlfredBalle - Add an `| xxd -r -p` after the plaintext for the hex decoding and the `-nopad` option in the openssl statement to disable padding.

Comment: Ah, yes `-nopad`. Brains' mush at the moment.

Comment: Is it possible to se how to decrypt?

Comment: Oh come on :). Reverse the `xxd` command to get binary again, then use the `-d` option for `openssl`, it's not that hard.